# jquerymobile: how to load page content inside a DIV using $.mobile.changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have page1.html, page2.html, I want to load page2.html content inside page1.html's 
can I achieve this by using $.mobile.changePage function?
Thanks,
nehatha

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so. Use the regular jQuery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Comment: Thank you Paul, but I want to have jquerymobile tranistions like slidedown, slideup, pop,... How can I get those transitions

Comment: You want a transition *inside* another page according to your question. That's not usually how it works. You transition from one page to another.

Comment: My requirement is, I need to fix the left navigation bar, need to load the pages in the main content's div with  transition effect.

Comment: If you want to load a page fragment and animate it into an existing page, then I think you will have to load the fragment and then animate it separately after the fragment has loaded. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for how to animate DOM elements, and you would animate the DOM element you have loaded via `load` function.